# HTTP ERROR 500 in PHP but syntax is correct

Tags: php, syntax, http-status-code-500

I have the following code and a program is trying to access it but I get a 500 error. I checked the syntax and everything else was working perfectly fine.

One important thing to note is that a moved servers, and that's when I noticed this started happening but I cannot pint point on the issue.

Please note that I have changed business name, phone numbers, and emails for privacy.

```
<?php

require_once('PHPMailer-
master/class.phpmailer.php');

/**
* This section ensures that Twilio gets a response.
*/
header('Content-type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

$dial_call_status = $_REQUEST['DialCallStatus'];
if($dial_call_status == "completed" || $dial_call_status == "answered"){


$email = new PHPMailer();
$email->From = 'info@somedomain.com';
$email->FromName = 'Business Name';
$email->Subject = "New number calling from  
{$_REQUEST['From']}";
$email->Body = "The call comes from the following city {$_REQUEST['FromCity']}, {$_REQUEST['FromState']}. Mp3 attached.";
$email->AddAddress( 'user1@somedomain.com' , 'Mar');
$email->AddAddress( 'user2@somedomain.com' , 'Rol');
$email->AddAddress( 'user3@somedomain.com' , 'Vic');

$recordingUrl = @$_REQUEST['RecordingUrl'];
$duration = @$_REQUEST['Duration'];
$durationRecording = @$_REQUEST['RecordingDuration'];
$callerId = @$_REQUEST['From'].'.mp3';
$attachment_data = file_get_contents($recordingUrl);

$email->addStringAttachment($attachment_data,$callerId, 'base64', 
'audio/mpeg3');

if ($durationRecording < 1.0) {
exit;
} else {
return $email->Send();
}

}else{
?>
<Response>
<Sms from="+1555555555" to="+18188888884">Mar didn't answer the call.</Sms>
<Sms from="+1555555555" to="+18188888886">Vic, someone is calling you.</Sms>
<Pause length="4"/>
<Dial timeout="8" record="true" 
action="mail1.php">
    <Number url="whisper.xml">+18188888886</Number>
 </Dial>
 </Response>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
```

I also checked the syntax using

```
php -l mail.php
```

and it returned

```
no syntax errors detected in mail.php
```

Comment: you've got a bunch of weird line breaks in there. also, you might get a 500 if the script dies before it gets a chance to output anything, so since you have that `require_once` before your first output, I would investigate if `class.phpmailer.php` is being included correctly and not bombing out

Comment: What are server logs telling you?